# Paths that will work an any computer - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I try to do a script that will delete specific files.
These files can be located differently on any pc, for example:
On my pc: C:\Users\TestA\Example
Other pcs: D:\Users\TestB\Example

You see, I want to delete the "example" but the problem is that I dont know where the files are located on the other pcs.

Therefore the script should find it itself. What should the script find? The driver letter like C:\ or D:\ etc. and the file itself with the path that I dont know.

What I did:
Use * instead of username:
C:\Users\Felix\File
C:\Users*\File
-> obviously this doesnt change the drive problem cause it could be located anywhere.

For the drive letter, I think the script could test if the path exist with Test-Path or check for certain folder names.
But I dont know how that could be related with eachother in the context given above.

Comment: Perhaps you're just looking for `"$env:USERPROFILE\Example"`? If the path is truly completely variable, you're better off not trying to guess it or search for the file (which could be extremely slow) but just demanding the user specify the location.

Comment: Another point against guessing: what if there are multiple "example" directories, and the script is not supposed to delete some (or any!) of those?

Comment: How would *you* find the file manually in the file system if you were sitting at that computer? Where would you look, and what guidelines would you use to locate it? If you can't answer that you're not going to be able to write a script to automate it...